# How can I verify that I'm using the correct project ID in Google Cloud

Tags: gcloud

I just created a virtual instance using Google Cloud but I have three projects and it assigned the instance to the wrong project. It really looks like this is a bug but how I can I be sure that the fault lies with Google and not me.  Also, someone is inevitably going to advise me to use the cloud console to create instances so let me preempt that advice.  I'm trying to get all of my cloud computing down to the click of one button.  I plan on regularly creating and destroying instances and I have to be able to do this quickly and efficiently.  Hence, all of my cloud computing has to be done with Python. In any case, I have two projects: 'move_files', and '9920' (I didn't make up the names).  I used the following python syntax:

```
import subprocess
str1 = "/users/kylefoley/codes/move.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = str1

def create_instance(name='', machine_type=''):
    name = 'kfoley76'
    machine_type = 'n1-standard-1'

    subprocess.run(['gcloud', 'compute', 'instances', 'create',
                    name, f'--machine-type={machine_type}',
                    '--zone=us-west2-a'])

create_instance()
```

That code resulted in an instance being created on the 'atomic' project rather than the 'move' project and yet my google application credentials clearly stated otherwise.  The only thing I can think of is that somehow I named the `json` file incorrectly.  But how would I verify that?

Also, let me provide proof that the wrong project ID houses the instances.  I guess I won't be able to keep the names secret but I suppose that they cannot be stolen unless someone has my password. The atomic project is really called 9920:

[image: the move files project (no instances)]

[image: the 9920 project]

Comment: The [Method: `projects.get( )`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/get) will help you get your project information, such as name, parent, projectId, and projectNumber. You can use the Python Client Library. Then, you can execute the [`gcloud config set project my-project`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#project), where `my-project` is your projectId, which will allow to specify the project ID of Google Cloud Platform to operate on by default. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a different (better) approach than using Python to make `gcloud` calls. While your current approach will work, it's more complex than necessary, makes error-handling more challenging and -- as you've seen -- can result in unexpected behavior. In this case, because you're calling out to `gcloud`, you're also inheriting its configuration.

The alternative is to use [Google's Python SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client). All Google's services (e.g. Compute Engine) are accessible via Google-provided SDKs. There are 2 primary flavors of SDK. The older, API Client Libraries and the newer (and only for [some] Cloud services [and unfortunately not Compute Engine]) Cloud Client Libraries. Here's Google's [explainer](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).

**NB** `gcloud` is itself written in Python and uses the API Client Libraries.

Google's API documentation is excellent. Every service (not just Cloud) and every method is fully (and correctly|automatically) documented. Here's Compute Engine's Instance Insert method:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert

**NB** The page also presents Google's APIs Explorer which enables you to make the API call directly to observe the behavior.

If you scroll down this page, you will find example for each of the languages supported by Google:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert#examples

See this page for the example too:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide

**NB** When you use (any of) the APIs directly, you must explicitly state which project to use. This is because, `gcloud` permits defaults e.g. `gcloud config set project` but the APIs themselves are stateless and do not.

**NB** My personal recommendation is to never use `gcloud config set ...` as this can result in problems like this. I think it's better to always explicitly reference e.g. the project, with `gcloud` commands using e.g. `gcloud ... --project=${PROJECT} ...`

Comment: "Google's API documentation is excellent."  -- Absolutely not.  But then again so is 90% of all documentation I've ever read, so Google's API is average as far as documentation goes, but that's like saying, this trash dump is average as far as trash dumps go.

Comment: Let me give you an example as to how bad the documentation is.  Suppose I want to rewrite the code `    subprocess.run(['ssh-keygen', '-t', 'rsa', '-f', '/users/kylefoley/.ssh/ssh_key' ,'-C', 'kylefoley76'])` using the google api.  I put in ssh into the search window and nothing even comes us.

Comment: @kylefoley76 `subprocess` is a Python module (not a Google API). When you use `subprocess` your Python programming is spawning the `gcloud` program as a separate process. I recommend you not use `subprocess` to run `gcloud` commands (to then invoke Google APIs) but to use the Google Cloud API for Compute Engine directly in your Python program.