# How do you create an instance using google-api-client?

Tags: python, gcloud, google-api-client

When I run a python program it's as simple as writing into terminal `python myprogram.py`.  Now, I'm trying to run that program on a google vm instance and shut it off with as few steps as possible. I'm trying to get it all written down in a python program, but I was told that my method of using the subprocess module is not the right way to do it.  I was told that the best way to do it is to use the `googleapiclient` module. So the current I use to create an instance is:

```
def create_instance(name='', machine_type=''):
    name = 'kfoley76'
    machine_type = 'n1-standard-1'

    subprocess.run(['gcloud', 'compute', 'instances', 'create',
                     name, f'--machine-type={machine_type}',
                     '--zone=us-west2-a', '--boot-disk-auto-delete'])
```

How would I rewrite that using `googleapiclient` module.  I assume the answer would be located here

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start

but that documentation is utterly incomprehensible.

Comment: Have you looked into Google's Python sample code? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/81a8413528860ff368a3e9f3b7f4e3665588d07f/compute/api/create_instance.py

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide) I mentioned in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59474437/609290) to your other question. I'm confident it will get you exactly what you need.

Comment: In the following code: `def create_instance(compute, project, zone, name, bucket):
    image_response = compute.images().getFromFamily(
        project='debian-cloud', family='debian-9').execute()
    source_disk_image = image_response['selfLink']` it's not clear what type of object `compute` is.

Comment: It's a service object. See https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/start.md#build-the-service-object